Knots or Fringes on bottom of Tallis Katan
I have noticed that on some pairs of tzitzis you see these "poofs" at the bottom of the beged, what significance is there? Is it a halachic thing or a practical thing?
I've been looking through mi yodeya and have found a few people answer, one stating that it's the former, where, the front is more holy so it shouldn't be confused with the back.
I was thinking that this has a few problems, namely being, why specifically knot them up? Some pairs of tzitzis have a few extra black lines at the front so wouldn't that be a good enough distinction anyway? Also, if that's the case, why is it only on SOME tzitzis? (especially Chassidish).
I've also heard that it's just practicality, and at the end of the tzitzis beged there is some loose wool so they knot it up into a ball. But with modern technology, I suppose we'd be able to sew the ends? So... is anyone able to tell me what the significance of the "double fringes" - as they're called - are, if any?



Welcome to MiYodeya Gershon and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

related: Little knots of wool on the bottom/side of the Tzitzit
